# Can't get order data in a sales_order_place_after model observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have an extension that's running with the end goal of subscribing a user to a mailing list when they order a specific product. I have the script working 100% fine outside of my Observer.php, but for some reason the same code doesn't work in Observer.php because `loadByIncrementId()` is producing a very empty looking object.

So for example here's what I have:

```
class Namespace_Extension_Model_Observer
{
    public function Myfunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order_number = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_number); 
    }
}
```

It gets `$order_number` fine, but $order doesn't give me the results I'm expecting. I can't think of anything other than firing a curl to my script that does work and passing the order number to it, which sounds like an ugly way out

Comment: can u plz show ur script code..

Comment: You already have an order. Why to load it again?

Comment: If I use just $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); for some reason that causes the checkout to just timeout and break

Answer (score 2):

`sales_order_place_after` is dispatched before the order actually gets saved to the database (right before the transaction is committed). The next event after the transaction is complete would be `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`.

But loading the order again that just has been saved will give you no benefit, so just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an order, so you don't have to load it:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

Comment: I thought that too, but when I tried that it breaks the final checkout process, it times out